# Add class and change HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add a class and change text in my paragraph every time a button is clicked. How can I do this? I am very new to JavaScript, so any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
HTML

<h1 id="heading">Hello!</h1>
<button onClick = "good()">Click Me</button>

CSS
.pink{
   color:pink;
}
.blue{
   color:blue;           
}
.red {
    color:red;
}

JS


function good(){
var computerChoice = Math.random();
var heading = document.getElementById('heading'); 


if(computerChoice <= 0.33 ){
    heading.innerHTML =  "This is a good!";
    heading.addClass(pink);


    }
if(computerChoice >= 0.67 ){
    heading.innerHTML =  "This is a bad";
    heading.addClass(blue);   
    }
else {
        heading.innerHTML =  "This is else"; 
}       heading.addClass(red);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You were very close! Though you have a few errors.

The first is that in pure javascript (without jQuery) you need to use `.classList.add` instead of `.addClass` (*look at my note down below*)

The second is that you need to include parenthesis around the class names `blue`, `pink`, and `red` when you're adding the class

The third is that the last `.classList.add` was outside of the `else`, it should be inside of it

The fourth is that you  need to use `if` the first time, `else if` the second statement, and `else` to catch the rest

```
function good() {
    var computerChoice = Math.random();
    var heading = document.getElementById('heading');

    if (computerChoice <= 0.33) {
        heading.innerHTML = "This is a good!";
        heading.classList.add('pink');
    }    
    else if (computerChoice >= 0.67) {
        heading.innerHTML = "This is a bad";
        heading.classList.add('blue');
    } else {
        heading.innerHTML = "This is else";
        heading.classList.add('red');
    }    
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/SK7Qy/6/)

One note as well: Using the `classList.add` method, if you click the button multiple times then the element can have multiple of the various classes, meaning both `red` and `blue` for example. The color of the text will then be determined by the one declared in the CSS later on, in your case `blue` will default over `pink` and `red` will default over `blue` and `pink`

To fix this you could use `.className = 'red'`, etc. instead. This is the approach you should be using! [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/SK7Qy/8/)

Alternatively, you could `.add` the class(es) you want and `.remove` the other(s) in a given state.

Answer (score 1):

`.addClass` method is available in jQuery not in pure javascript. You can use `setAttribute` method the set the attribute of the DOM Element. In this case you can set the `class` attribute

```
heading.setAttribute("class", "pink");
```

You can also use the `.className` property to set the class name in javascript.

```
heading.className="pink"
```

apart from this there are some errors too

You are adding red class after all the statement which make no sense that should be inside the else statement.

You need to use `else if` for second statement otherwise you will never get the first `if`  statement result.

```
function good() {
 var computerChoice = Math.random(0, 1);
 alert(computerChoice);
 var heading = document.getElementById('heading');
 if (computerChoice <= 0.33) {
     heading.innerHTML = "This is a good!";
     heading.setAttribute("class", "pink");
 } else if (computerChoice >= 0.67) {
     heading.innerHTML = "This is a bad";
     heading.setAttribute("class", "blue");
 } else {
     heading.innerHTML = "This is else";
     heading.setAttribute("class", "red");
 }
```

}

**[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MTdc6/)**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using jQuery..

```
var heading = $('#heading'); 


if(computerChoice <= 0.33 ){
    heading.html("This is a good!");
    heading.addClass(pink);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

a pure javascript solution that supports older browsers would be using element.className with the "+=" operator to add additional class to the element.

```
function good(){
var computerChoice = Math.random();
var heading = document.getElementById('heading'); 
if(computerChoice <= 0.33 ){
heading.innerHTML =  "This is a good!";
heading.className+='pink';
}
if(computerChoice >= 0.67 ){
heading.innerHTML =  "This is a bad";
heading.className +='blue';   
}
else {
heading.innerHTML =  "This is else"; 
}       
heading.className +='red';
}
```